# Which character from Star Trek (TNG era) "died" the most times?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

This question revolves around the most times a character from the TNG era (including DS9, Voyager and movies) died.

This question involves spoilers.  Do not read on if you haven't watched all the episodes/movies and don't want to know.

"Death" here includes, temporary death, brain death, reversed death, presumed death, holographic death, imagined death, hallucinated death.   The death doesn't need to be portrayed on-screen.   Repeated death in the same episode or portraying the same event counts as one death.

Examples to clarify what counts:

> * In "Cause and Effect", everyone on board died (then it was undone in a time loop)
>  
>  * In "Skin of Evil", Yar dies.   After the events of "Yesterday's Enterprise", we learn in  "Redemption Part II" that she died in the past.
>  
>  * In "Tapestry", Picard dies on the operating table, and then comes back, possibly due to intenvention from Q.
>  
>  * In "Timescape", everyone on-board except Picard, Data, La Forge, and Troi die when the Enterprise exploded, but the time reverses itself.
>  
>  * In "Thine Own Self", holographic La Forge is sent to his death by Troi.
>  
>  * In *Star Trek Nemesis*, Data dies.

The point is not to argue over whether a particular event constitutes death or not.   If it looks like death or is called death, it probably counts.

Inevitably I will be editing this more to clarify more as needed.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/66290/3823

Comment: I would like to point out that in Cause and Effect the entire crew dies something like 17 times (17.4 days in the loop, and around 1 day or less for each loop).  So any deaths that include this should start at 17 at least.

Comment: @Michael:  Reread the description.  This kind of episode, such as "Cause and Effect" and "Coda" are exactly the reason I said we count multiple deaths in the same episode as one.   Furthermore, in "Parallels" there are going to be enough Enterprises to fill the sector.  Out of our sample size of three, the one Worf is on and probably the destroyed one with Cast Away Riker have Picard dead.   So you can assume out of trillions of Enterprises that there aren't only two with a dead Picard.   Do you want to count this as billions of dead Picards?

Comment: How does Data fit into this question? Is deactivation considered dying? He does have an on/off switch. Depending on the interpretation, I'd expect Data's count to be pretty high.

Comment: @Ellesedil:   Off is not dead, just like stasis is not dead.

Comment: I've downvoted this question. You've made the definition of "death" so fuzzy that debate about what is and is not included is essential, and apparently mods are cleaning up the comments intended to seek clarification. As such, this *cannot* receive a proper answer. (It probably ought to be closed. I think it falls into at least "Unclear what you're asking" and "Primarily Opinion Based." Maybe into "Too Broad," too.)

Comment: Eh, I guess. So does that mean that the only way Data can actually die is if his body is disintegrated like in *Nemesis*? Is Data considered dead in *Time's Arrow* even though he's returned to health through normal means? Since Data is a machine, as long as he physically exists, he could always be returned to consciousness. But, does that mean if Data's consciousness is stored somewhere, can he actually die? What if he's completely disassembled, is he dead then?

Comment: @jpmc26:   It's a frickin' sci-fi show with people dying up to 15 times -- of course it's hard to define what constitutes "dead"  !!

Comment: @jpmc26: Furthermore, the way this is dealt with in other questions like [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99469/3823) and [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99535/3823) excellent answer is to explain the clear cases and explain the borderline ones.   Shows have ambiguity -- it won't always be possible to explain restrictions so that everyone agrees what is in or out.   And furthermore if even you could, does it actually improve a question to add enough seemingly arbitrary restrictions to achieve that?   Just answer the question and note the ambiguities.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Except there are too many borderline cases here. You're not going to be able to cover *all* of them. The previous stretches made in Praxis' answer demonstrates that. Additionally, many comments seeking clarifications were deleted by moderators. Apparently, the level of discussion required to resolve the ambiguities is being discouraged, and without the opportunity to clarify, this question isn't answerable. Of course it's hard to define as you say, but the level of ambiguity here is making it a bad fit for StackExchange's format. That's not an attack; it's just a reality.

Comment: @jpmc26:   I get your point, but clearly 23 people do approve of the question and 34 people do approve of Praxis's answer.   **That's** the reality.     I would also add, it's not disapproval for the mods to delete comments.   Comments are to improve a question or answer and it's normal procedure to delete those comments if there are too many and after clarifications or suggestions to improve may have been applied to the questions or answers.

Comment: Except the mods deleted at least one comment before it was resolved (and it still hasn't been resolved); I know this because it was mine. I only downvoted and left my comment after this happened. If they don't want that much discussion going on, it's fine, but it means we won't be able to effectively discuss to get clarification. *That's* why I say it's not a good fit for the Q&A format: it requires *so much* clarification that the discussion is so long that moderators are intervening.

Comment: @jpmc26:   Then you [take it to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley)

Comment: @ThePopMachine +1 for "Cast Away Riker."  So that makes Data (in that universe) Wilson?  I think this is crying out for a crossover fanfic.

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller:   He took "[grow the beard](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GrowingTheBeard)" a little [too far](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/b/ba/Riker_gone_mad.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20141225201810&path-prefix=en) in that timeline.

Comment: Fyi, I decided to raise a [Meta question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7171/25379) about whether moving the clarification to chat is acceptable and can make this question on-topic.

Answer (score 36):

## I nominate Picard: 10 "deaths".

- ["Time Squared"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Squared_(episode)): Picard shoots and kills another Picard.  (Not a hologram or clone and not an imagined death, but an identical Picard who was from a slightly different moment in time.)
- ["Samaritan Snare"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Samaritan_Snare_(episode)): Although not terribly explicit, some of the dialogue suggests that Picard may have been briefly, clinically dead on the operating table (he had no metabolic processes at one point).  Ultimately, he was saved by Pulaski.
- ["Cause and Effect"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_(episode)): Everyone on board dies (then it gets undone in a time loop).
- ["Tapestry"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tapestry_(episode)): He dies on the operating table, and then comes back, possibly due to intenvention from Q.
- ["Chain of Command"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chain_of_Command,_Part_I_(episode)): Presumed dead after being captured by the Cardassians.
- ["Parallels"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Parallels_(episode)): Picard is dead in various alternate timelines. The deaths are not shown on-screen, but that seems to be okay by the guidelines of the question.  Also by the guidelines, this gets counted as one death (no matter how many timelines he dies in).
- ["Gambit"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gambit,_Part_I_(episode)): Picard is declared dead after he is "killed" by a transporter weapon.
- ["All Good Things"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/All_Good_Things..._(episode)): Two Enterprises blow up, presumably ending two Picards.  Will count these as one death.
- [*Generations*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Generations) : Picard looks to have died on Veridian III (due to explosion of the Veridian star) just as Kirk seemed to have died aboard the Enterprise-B.  In actuality, Picard was saved by the Nexus (just as Kirk was), and we find this out a few moments later.
- ["Azati Prime"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Azati_Prime_%28episode%29): This is an *Enterprise* episode that takes place partly in the 26th Century.  By this time, Picard would surely be dead.  (I'm only including this one because of the "Living Witness" example in the Janeway answer, even though it means that Janeway's count should increase by 1 too, as a result.)

**Fringe cases**

These instances are debatable, but given the OP's loose definition of "death", they may be relevant.  Here they are for posterity at the very least, or in case they are relevant to someone answering a future question.

- ["Lonely Among Us"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lonely_Among_Us_(episode)): Picard exists for a period of time only as some sort of energy field out in space.  He eventually gets saved by the power of terrible sci-fi.  I want to file this under "temporary death", even though his consciousness still seemed to exist...somewhere out there.  Also discussed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/66290/3823).
- ["The Best of Both Worlds"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Best_of_Both_Worlds_(episode)): Picard is declared a "casualty of war" by Admiral Hanson.  He was not dead, but considered *good as dead*.
- ["The Inner Light"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Inner_Light_(episode)): Picard's alternate probe-based persona presumably dies, outside of the simulation.  But we'll never know for sure.
- ["Remember Me"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Remember_Me_(episode)): Crusher is trapped in a static warp bubble and everyone else around her slowly disappears. Picard is one of the last to cease existing before we really know what is going on.  It's true that Crusher has a hunch about what is going on before Picard disappears, but we (the viewers) don't know that she is *right* yet.
- ["Frame of Mind"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Frame_of_Mind_(episode)): Riker shoots himself and "shatters" his imagined Picard in the process.
- [*Nemesis*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Nemesis) : Picard's clone dies.

Some of these are fringe cases, but do fall into the death "types" listed by the OP in the question.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Picard doesn't die at all in *The Inner Light*. The simulation just ends after the rocket launches (and he gets to speak with some people who had passed away in the simulation).

Comment: @jpmc26 : I've reorganized the answer considerably in response to your concerns and other commenters.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I took it as a challenge to myself to see how many Picard deaths I could find, based mainly on your own hunch, and to see if I could top the Janeway count.  I've been at my office for most of the day, and so I wasn't able to respond to most of your comments or make edits in response.  Anyway, I've reorganized the answer considerably.  I'm keeping "Samaritan Snare", but all the other questionable ones have been lumped out of the count.

Comment: @Praxis:   Nice work.   I still personally would have put Lonely Among Us in the Fringe cases section.   He's not thought dead, just irretrievable.  Same case as BOBW...

Comment: @Praxis:    But what I really take issue with is "Azati Prime".  This is just an episode that happens to take place in the future, so you're assuming Picard is dead.   The reason this is not like "Living Witness" is because in LW, there is actual dialog about the crew of Voyager, paraphrasing: "It is safe to assume all your friends (incl. Janeway) are dead."   **EMH is presuming Janeway is dead.**   There's no mention of Picard in Azati Prime and nor even any relationship between any character in "Azati Prime" and Picard.   You're really pushing a loophole to the point of breaking here.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : (1) I meant to move "Lonely Among Us" (honest).  I'll do that now. (2) As I mentioned earlier, they only say "it's safe to say they're dead" in "Living Witness".  That's *not* a declaration of death.  For all we know, immortality could have been discovered when Janeway was 99.  I'm saying it's "safe to say" Picard is dead in the same way it is "safe to say" Janeway is dead.  My point is, the two episodes should be accepted or discounted, but not one over the other.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : "Lonely Among Us" moved.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : The EMH did not make such a verbal presumption.  He was only told that it's safe to say your friends are dead.

Comment: @Praxis:   What are the relative probabilities of living 800 years over being reconstituted from an energy cloud?  [I don't know?  *Do you?*  **Do you?** ***Do you?***](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/135.htm)

Comment: @ThePopMachine : lol

Comment: Shouldn't each time from "Cause and Effect" count? If I recall correctly, they all died 3 or 4 times during that episode (not counting the other loops which weren't shown) - nevermind, just seen the rule about multiple deaths = 1 death ;) Missed it at first!

Comment: When you said "Captured by the Cardassians" I thought, "Well death would definitely be preferable.  I thought it said Kardashians.

Comment: Gambut shouldn't be on the list. It was an illusion. If you saw David Copperfield perform an illusion where it looked like he was sawed in half, but then it was revealed to be an illusion, would you list him as a double amputee in his biography?

Comment: related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66290/how-many-times-is-captain-picard-shown-to-die-or-implied-to-die-on-tng

Comment: @PopularIsn'tRight : He was declared "dead" in the episode.  The question specifically asks for instances that include "presumed death" and "imagined death".  From the question: *"Death" here includes, temporary death, brain death, reversed death, presumed death, holographic death, imagined death, hallucinated death. The death doesn't need to be portrayed on-screen."* (Also, you are spelling "Gambit" incorrectly.)

Comment: At some point in the *Picard* show, he dies and is replaced by an android version of himself, that's one more.  (I haven't watched the whole show, I've just heard about this - there might be other instances I don't know about?)

Answer (score 17):

## Kathryn Janeway: 15 "deaths"

While I was researching the deaths of another Voyager character I stumbled across this video that sums 17 deaths of Kathryn Janeway:

Even if you count the 4 different deaths in the episode "Coda" as one, the count from the video is still 14:

1. ["Time and Again"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Time_and_Again_(episode))
2. ["Deadlock"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deadlock_(episode)): Voyager self destructs to save it's duplicate
3. ["Coda"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Coda_(episode)): Chakotay and Janeway get cought in an (imagined) time loop. She dies 4 different deaths in this episode.
4. ["Before and After"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Before_and_After_(episode)): Janeway gets killed by an exploding console on the bridge
5. ["Worst Case Scenario"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Worst_Case_Scenario_(episode)): A holographic Janeway gets killed by a sabotaged phaser rifle
6. ["Year of Hell"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Year_of_Hell_(episode)): Janeway steers Voyager in a collision
7. (["Living Witness"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Living_Witness_(episode)): Set far into the future. One could argue that everybody dies someday)
8. ["Timeless"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Timeless_(episode)): Voyager crash lands on a planet
9. ["Course Oblivion"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Course:_Oblivion_(episode)): The copy of Voyager including crew from the episode "Demon" disintegrates
10. ["Barge of the Dead"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Barge_of_the_Dead_(episode)): Janeway gets stabbed in the back in B'Elanas death vision
11. ["Tinker Tenor Doctor Spy"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tinker_Tenor_Doctor_Spy_(episode)): Janewaz gets killed in a daydream by The Doctor
12. ["Shattered"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shattered_(episode)): Janeway is told in a different timeline that she died
13. ["Relativity"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Relativity_(episode)): Voyager is destroyed with Janeway on board
14. ["Endgame"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Endgame_(episode)): Admiral Janeway lets herself killed by the Borg to allow her younger self to escape

Not mentioned in the video:

15. ["Message in a Bottle"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Message_in_a_Bottle_(episode)): We learn that the Voyager is declared lost by Starfleet Command and that the crew including Janeway is presumed dead

Comment: By the rules set out, "Coda" counts for one, not four.

Comment: Nice work.  But given some of these types of deaths, I can definitely increase Picard's count.

Comment: *Coda* is not really a time loop. It's all just in Janeway's head.

Comment: It just occurred to me that Voyager was declared lost by Starfleet Command (as learned by The Doctor in "Message in a Bottle"). Would that count as "presumed dead"?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, yes, I believe so.

Comment: #7 doesn't count. We don't know that she's dead.

Comment: @Richard the Doctor presumes she is dead.

Comment: Everyone presumed that Scotty was dead. Until they found out that he wasn't.